# ¿Cómo añadir Toast en Android?

Tags: android-layout

Mi problema es que nesecito hacer que salte un mensaje *Toast* al iniciar la aplicacion cada ves que ingrese en ella.

Adjunto una imagen para ver lo que quiero hacer.
Resulta que solo se que para ello se escribe el siguiente codigo:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hola Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Nesesito de su ayuda pues no se como escribirlo correctamente, con la ubicación no estoy del todo seguro pues en un tutorial dice que es en: *androidmanifest.xml*, y en otro me dice que es en: res/layaout, pero no tengo claro si ello es cierto. saludos y muchas gracias por su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes mostrar  lo que has intentado, no es por maldad pero si no muestras tu fragmento de código no te ayudaran, de paso debes decir en que lenguaje estas programando si en Java o Kotlin coloca las etiquetas respectivas a tu publicación(Aunque por el código  Toast que escribiste demuestras que es en Java ) pero igual manera debes  detallarlo mejor. Y mi consejo es que si no sabes manejar aun el lenguaje o el framework  de Android puedes mirar videos tutoriales porque aquí no se enseña a manejar el Android desde cero amigo,

Comment: El codigo escrito es en java, y lo unico que nesecito saber es Donde lo pego o copio para que funcione.

Comment: Verifica si [ésto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500197/how-to-display-toast-in-android) responde o ayuda a tu pregunta

Comment: Solo necesitas poner esa linea de código que muestras en el *Activity* donde quieres mostrar el *Toast*. En tu caso según veo tu necesidad seria en el método *onCreate*. Puedes encontrar bastante información en la web sobre ésto [(Aquí un ejemplo)](https://www.sgoliver.net/blog/notificaciones-en-android-i-toast/)

Comment: Israel-ICM, Gracias por tu respuesta encotre codigos corectos en el enlace que me proporcionastes pero sigo sin saber adonde o en que archivo tengo que ubicarlo para que trabaje. Si puedes ayudarme con eso es de mucha ayuda para mi GRACIAS.

Comment: Ni en el manifiesto ni en /res/layout. Tendrás que añadirlo en una de tus Activity.java. Esto es algo bastante básico en Android. Diría que el tutorial que estás tratando de seguir es más avanzado que tu nivel actual (porque el tutorial que te indica @Israel-ICM es bastante ilustrativo). Intenta buscar otro más básico de introducción.

Comment: Bueno talvez [éste link](https://www.universoandroidhn.com/2018/04/android-studio-toast.html) te ayude un poco más, pero creo que necesitas dar un repaso o buscar un tutorial más básico como bien te comentan ya que comprender como funcionan las actividades es muy importante en android.

Answer (score 1):

"necesito hacer que se muestre un mensaje Toast al iniciar la aplicación cada ves que ingrese en ella"

Esto lo puedes realizar en la `Activity` inicial dentro de su método `onCreate()` y el crear el `Toast` es precisamente como lo estas realizando y no tienes que realizar ninguna modificación dentro del `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hola Bienvenido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```